# Howt o use DTO for elements of a GetCollection operation in api-platform 3 without loosing doctrine query based pagination info

Tags: symfony, doctrine, api-platform.com

I would like to have an endpoint for listing of an entity, which is a doctrine managed entity.
In this listing endpoint I want some properties which are not part of the entity.
As stated in documentation this should be represented by an DTO where I can modify the representation. For single entity GET operation this works fine.

For the GetCollection operation I need a provider where I can instanciate the dto's.
To maintain the doctrine filter and pagination logic I duplicated the default doctrine Provider (ApiPlatform\Doctrine\Orm\State\CollectionProvider)

In this provider I got a ApiPlatform\Doctrine\Orm\Paginator Object. I can iterate that and build a result set(array) of my DTO's and return that, but then I lose the pagination information in the serialized output.

### How can I preserve this information?

A solution based on Benjamins answer(I'm not allowed to edit there):

```
# reuse doctrine collection provider
App\State\EntityProvider:
    bind:
        $collectionProvider: '@api_platform.doctrine.orm.state.collection_provider'
------
EntityProvider implements ProviderInterface {
    public function __construct(
        readonly private ProviderInterface $collectionProvider, readonly private ResourceMetadataCollectionFactoryInterface $collectionFactory){}
        
    public function provide(...)
        $collection = $this->collectionFactory->create...
        $paginator = $this->collectionProvider->provide($collection, $uriVariables, $context);
        
        #rewrite resultset
        $results_new = []; 
        foreach($paginator as $result ) {
            $results_new[] = ...}
            
        return new TraversablePaginator(new \ArrayObject($results_new), $paginator->getCurrentPage(), $paginator->getItemsPerPage(), $paginator->getTotalItems());
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the information public? it's not a problem of serialization group?

Comment: sorry i dont understand your answer. but the serialization groups is not what i am looking into, because of many different representations of some entities i rather want to use specific dto's for every use case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the [documentation](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/pagination/#pagination-for-custom-state-providers), you should just return in your custom provider a `ApiPlatform\State\Pagination\PartialPaginatorInterface` or a `ApiPlatform\State\Pagination\PaginatorInterface` and API-Platform will take care of the rest. You have already implemented object available:

- `ApiPlatform\State\Pagination\ArrayPaginator`
- `ApiPlatform\State\Pagination\TraversablePaginator`

Comment: I had read this, but because i already have a paginator at this point, i ignored it. But you are right i have to build a new paginator based on transformed data.